# Automate user creation

Tags: php, mysql, ftp, adduser

I have a site for my students, and it is running on Ubuntu 14.04. When my students register themselves on my site, I store user info in an MySQL DB.

I would like to give my students a website on my Ubuntu installation, when registering on my site, and I would like this to be automated. My question is - Can I somehow use the data direct from the MySQL DB to give them a subdomain (username.mydoamin.com) on my Ubuntu or can i execute shell commands on Ubuntu from PHP, and automate what I am doing manually now?

Comment: Well i guess adding user and creating websites automatically on Ubuntu doesn´t qualify - Or maybe I explained my question in a bad way?

Comment: It might also be my fault, I have nearly no knowledge in PHP, but I personally can't see any connection with Ubuntu here, but only website design with PHP. Am I wrong? If yes, please clarify this.

Comment: ByteCommander - I will try to clarify. From my point of view this almost nothing to do with webdesign. What I am really asking is how to automate user creation on Ubuntu and since I already have users on my website (running on Ubuntu) I was curious if I could use either the exiting info in the exiting DB on Ubuntu, or if I could automate it through the PHP. This is my opinion more askig in (and learning about) Ubuntu. I might be wrong :)

Comment: You want to create linux user accounts? I thought you meant a kind of user account for your website... Then please forgive me. :)

Comment: Its perfectly OK - The written language can be quite confusing sometimes, and my English is probably not the best - When trying to explain problems I do not know how to solve myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i execute shell commands on Ubuntu from PHP, and automate what I am doing manually now?

You can run shell commands from within `PHP` using the [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function or using the `` ` ` `` (backtick) operator: if you're running `PHP` < 5.4.0, first make sure to disable [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php), then in your `PHP` script you can use either of those syntaxes:

- `$return = shell_exec('<shell_command>');`
- `` $return = `<shell_command>`; ``

Unless you want to capture return values from single commands, the most straightforward way to do what you're asking for would be to condensate everything you're doing manually in the shell into a stand-alone `bash` (or whatever) script to be called once by using either of those methods. For example the syntax for a `bash` script would be:

- `$return = shell_exec('bash script.sh');`
- `` $return = `bash script.sh`; ``

To pass parameters to the script (e.g. the value of a `$username` variable):

- `$return = shell_exec("bash script.sh '$username'");`
- `` $return = `bash script.sh '$username'`; ``

To retrieve the passed parameters within the `bash` script (e.g. the value of a `$username` variable passed with the method above):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# ...
username=$1
# ...
```

Or just simply reference `$1` where needed, e.g.:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# ...
echo "$1"
# ...
```

Comment: Kos - Thank you I will try it as soon as the kids are put to bed :) It seems pretty forward and a bliss that parameters are thrown that easy to the script. It has been more than 15 years since my last Linux experience - so I am very grateful for the help.

Comment: @BjarkeBundgaard You're welcome, I added two simple example on how to retrieve / use the passed parameters within the `bash` script either, I tought perhaps you might need them

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up on my own question I will elaborate with my experience. I made Shell execution work from PHP, but had major security issues with the solution. That was a MAJOR mistake from my hand that I did not see this at the beginning.

To eliminate security risks I made a bash script that looked activated users up in the user table. If the user was active AND not a linux user then the user should be created on my linux, a database user is created, a subdomain is created and ssh is locked for the user. I set up a cron job running every 60 minutes, and upon user creation an email is sent to the user with registration info.

That eliminates a lot of security risks (not all).

Bjarke